# Product of matrix powers with eigenvalue 1 and same eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Does there exist matrices $A$ and $B$ which are not idempotent and a row vector $v$ such that the following is satisfied?    Here $v$ is the left eigenvector of the matrices $AB$, $A^2B^2$, ... with eigenvalue $1$.

\begin{align*}
vAB&=v \\
vA^2B^2&=v\\
&\vdots\\
vA^nB^n &= v \\
&\vdots
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
vA &\neq v \\
vB &\neq v \\
AB &\neq BA \neq I \\
vBA  &\neq v
\end{align*}

If not, can we show that this is impossible?

Comment: @mfl but we're asked for $AB \neq I$. Edit: ah, Q was editted.

Comment: Thanks @mfl but I edited the question requiring that the product is not equal to identity matrix.

Comment: After two failing attempts to find matrices $A$ and $B$, I now tend to say that it is impossible. If $vA^nB^n=v\;\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$, I would expect $vA^{-1}B^{-1}=v$ for invertible $A$ and $B$, too (*just* *intuition*). Multiplying this from the right with $BA$, we get $v=vBA$, which contradicts the restrictions of the OP. I know that this is no proof at all, but it might serve as an indication for the impossibility of finding $A$ and $B$.